# Ansible pass value to installation commandline gui

Tags: ansible

How do I pass value to the commandline-gui prompt?

Like I typically install LAMP on a fresh Ubuntu using the following command.

```
sudo apt-get  install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin
```

And during install I am asked for a few inputs as below

[image: Commandline install prompt]

**So how do I pass/input values from a playbook?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using Ansible, you would generally install the packages non-interactively, like this [1]:

```
- command: apt-get -y install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin
  environment:
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND: noninteractive
```

This will suppress any interactive configuration prompts during the
install.  You can then perform configuration tasks after the fact using
Ansible, either by directly manipulating files etc. or by using the
[debconf module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debconf_module.html).

If you're not familiar with debconf, [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/407317/passing-default-answers-to-apt-get-package-install-questions) has some information about interacting with the package configuration system.

[1] Actually, you would more often use the `package` module, but that doesn't support package groups like `lamp-server^`.